# setting -source to 1.5, it is set to 1.3 apparently

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven-2

I am using eclipse, with maven2 plugin.
I am trying to setup a simple annotations based spring 3 mvc web application.

So I went to RunAs and clicked on 'maven build', I set the goal as 'compile'.

When it compiles, I get the error message:

```
E:\dev\eclipse\springmvc2\src\main\java\web\HomeController.java:[5,1] annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
@Controller
```

so far I modified the eclipse.ini to use the jdk.  I also made sure under preferences, it is at java 1.6.

Not sure where else to change the java version?

(I am assuming source 1.3 means java 1.3 and that I need it to be at least version 1.5 compatible)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should also set a proper source version in `pom.xml` (because maven can make builds without Eclipse, so it can't use Eclipse preferences):

```
<project ...>    
    ...    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Comment: do I use my groupID and articleId there?

Comment: No, that's the groupID and artifactId of the plugin you like to configure. So you need to use exactly the values that are shown here.

Comment: @Blankman: No, these groupId and artifactId identify the maven-compiler-plugin

Comment: Ahh... the configuration hell of a modern development environment.