# Why I can't use Spring and Blossom annotations?

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, annotations, magnolia

I use Magnolia CMS and Blossom.
When I add annotations to my classes I get something like this:

> annotations are not supported in -source 1.3 (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
>   @Template(value="Blossom Template")*

Spring annotation(like @Controller) doesn't compile too.
Where is my mistake?

My pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-blossom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-admininterface</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-taglib-cms</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-taglib-utility</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: which jdk are you using, or more specifically compiling against

Comment: possible duplicate of [setting -source to 1.5, it is set to 1.3 apparently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233732/setting-source-to-1-5-it-is-set-to-1-3-apparently)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change your maven.compiler properties to compile with java 1.5.

```
<properties>
    <!-- maven-compiler-plugin configuration -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Another way to do this (but less discreet) is this :

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.5</source>
    <target>1.5</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

**Resources :**

- [http://maven.apache.org/ - compile MoJo - Source](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#source)

**On the same topic :**

- [How can I force maven to package my project against 1.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531260/how-can-i-force-maven-to-package-my-project-against-1-5/3531288#3531288)

Answer (score -2):

I am happy this got answered but encourage you to use the Magnolia community, especially the mailing-list to ask questions about Magnolia in the future. This will benefit you and the community.

See http://www.magnolia-cms.com/home/community/mailing-lists.html

Thanks
- Boris